# Don't return batch in the results

Tags: kql

Can I use a batch for temporal calculation, but eventually not include it in the results?

For example, I want to use 'temporal' tabular for calculation of other queries, but I do not want to get it later in the results (because it's too large). I.e. the results should contain *only Tables X and Y*.

```
requests
| take 1000 
| as temporal;
temporal | summarize count() | as X;
temporal | summarize avg(duration) | as Y;
```

P.s. using 'let' is impossible in my scenario

Comment: "using 'let' is impossible in my scenario". Why?

Comment: Because the inner query ('requests| take 1000' in the example) is configurable and may contain 'let' statements. let inside let won't work

Comment: Adi, kind reminder to close the loop, accept an answer (mark it with the green V), and upvote if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution you get just the results set you are interested in.
You might consider the code less "clean".

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let requests = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend duration = 1d * rand());
// Solution starts here.
requests
| take 1000 
| as hint.materialized=true temporal
| summarize count() | as X;
temporal | summarize avg(duration) | as Y;
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02Ou27DMAxFdwP%20hzvaHeJ4DvILXbo0I1ExjlA9XIoKisAfH8aJgWijeC7PHQZ8UZwDw5ESJk4spD6nHT6zYiZR5DP0wig51HXTNoEVwn%20VixYcEUlZPAV/404oTQyPs%20SIEZox7teHojzbzwL%20V04Orj5NdmB0%20IAlXdf3h7YZrNRLZimrUHBhYRNv0rZZoPTL63E8JjLGJ929dXFHlcpQjnMWCg%20q1BhJbIefXJN2Pdbkt0k3DO8UXadu6/liT4c7xn17vjQBAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you get an extra result set, however it is empty.

P.S.
You might want to use `hint.materialized=true` to prevent from the *temporal* data set to be computed twice.

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let requests = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend duration = 1d * rand());
// Solution starts here.
requests
| take 1000 
| as hint.materialized=true temporal
| take 0
;
temporal | summarize count() | as X;
temporal | summarize avg(duration) | as Y;
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WOu27CUAyG90h5h39MOhAyI16hS5cyWhwTjnouqY8PQoiHrxsI6lJvtv/LNwz4oDgHhiMlTJxYSH1OG7xnxUyiyCfomVFyqMunbQIrhL8rFy3YI5KyeAr%20xp1QmhgeJ8kRIzRj3C6Dojzb5Q6%20KicHVx9NFjA6vMGcruv7XdsMBvUsM5chFJxZ2IrX0ra5Q%20mLl3D8bmQan3Tzh8XtVSpDOc5ZKLw827axkvVsQKXGSGIOHHNN2vVY8j7/U9Fl6lb6p/aw%20wH5d/77SgEAAA==)